# How to find that a value is less than 108 and greater than 0 in JavaScript: something wrong in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, int

I write this code for checking:

```
var num = $("#knum").val();
        if (isNaN(parseInt(num))) {
            $("#errorknum").html("Please define a number.");
        }
        else {
            if (num < 1 | num > 249) {
                $("#errorkrnum").html("your number must be less then 249 and can be greater than 1");
            }
            else {
                $("#errorknum").html("");
            }
```

Everything is fine but, for example, when the user type `1242fdlfldsf` means it is 1242 but she accept it. How can I dishandle this value by code like for example: 23232dkfj

Comment: Two typos: 1) it's not greater then, it's greater than. 2) `|` should be `||`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

parseInt() should always be used with the second argument, in order to tell it that you expect a base-10 number:

```
parseInt(num, 10)
```

Also, you don't save its results so you are comparing strings.

And the single `|` is a bitwise operator. You probably want `||`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, when you do your OR comparison, you need to be using || not |:

```
if (num < 1 || num > 249)
```